# AWS secret manager javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, coldfusion, aws-sdk, aws-secrets-manager

I have java program to get Secretvalue from AWS secret manager and its working fine
I wanted to use this with ColdFusion so I created a runnable jar of java project and using the same jar in Coldfusion
and was working fine till last month but it throwing below error now

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not generate secret

Unable to execute HTTP request: Could not generate secret
```

below is my Java code and its working fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GetSecretValue getval = new GetSecretValue();
    String v1 = getval.getSecretV1("Key", "secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", "us-east-4");
    System.out.println("Secret value1 :: " + v1);
}
public String getSecretV1(String secretName, String endpoint, String region) {
   
    AWSSecretsManager client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(region)
        .build();

   
    String secret, decodedBinarySecret;
    GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest()
        .withSecretId(secretName);
    GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = null;

    try {
        getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
    } catch (DecryptionFailureException e) {
        return "Error: Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.";
    } catch (InternalServiceErrorException e) {
       return "Error: An internal service error occurred.";
    } catch (InvalidParameterException e) {
        return "Error: Invalid argument is passed.";
    } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
        return "Error: Something is wrong with the input to the request. For example, a required parameter may be missing or out of range.";
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        return "Error: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.";
    } 
    catch (SdkClientException e) {
        return "SdkClientException Exception :" +e.getMessage() + " || Cause : "+ e.getCause();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        return "Exception :" + e.getStackTrace();
    } 


    if (getSecretValueResult.getSecretString() != null) {
        secret = getSecretValueResult.getSecretString();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(secret);
        String objectString = obj.getString((String) obj.names().get(0));
        return objectString;

    } else {
        ByteBuffer binarySecretData = getSecretValueResult.getSecretBinary();
        return "error";
    }

}
```

please let me know what is changed in aws side or its it some other thing, also tried cacart and few other change please let know what is the issue and what should I try.

Comment: Try updating the JVM being used by ColdFusion.  Many times I've seen a similar error due to an out-of-date JVM.

Comment: Did you roll your own SDK or are you using the native AWS Java SDK? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/asm_access.html#asm-sdks

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno I am using native AWS and java SDK